# How to pass parameters from Suite class to Test class?

Tags: junit5

I am using JUnit5 suite feature, while running the suite file I want to pass some values to Base Test class, how to do that?. The way we do it in TestNG, passing parameters from runner file to the test
I want to pass different browser name from the suite class to the base class, like chrome, edge etc. Is there a way to do that?

here is my suite class:

```java
@Suite()
@SelectPackages("com.example.junitframework")
public class SuiteOne {

}
```

here is my base test class:

```java
public class BaseTest {
  @BeforeEach
  public void setup(){
    webDriver = initWebDriver("chrome"); // I want to take this method a parameter passed from Suite   class
  }
}
```

I tried calling @before each method from suite class, but that resulted in error due to implementation of TestWatcher.

Comment: Since `@Suite` is handled by a different test engine than your standard Jupiter test there is no straightforward way to achieve what you want. In order to suggest a suitable workaround I'd need to know if you want to run the same test class with different values in the same test run - or would it be two different test runs for let's say "chrome" and "firefox"?

Comment: it'd be 2 different tests, in first suite run I want to run all the tests on Chrome and on second suite run I want to run all the tests on Edge